# Add new field in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, backend

It has a custom module in my magento and I would like to add a new item in its scope by xml, I tried as I did other times but I am not getting

> adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <!--
        This item will be created in the Admin menu under Sales
        - If you want another section, reference the appropriate adminhtml.xml file in app/code/core/Mage/Modulename/etc
        - For example, we found out this was 'sales' by referencing the config/menu node of app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/adminhtml.xml
        -->
        <sales>
            <children>
                <!-- Here, I like to use the namespacename_modulename_controllername naming convention -->
                <calendario_calendario translate="title" module="calendario">
                    <!-- This is how the menu text will be displayed -->
                    <title>Bloqueio de Datas</title>
                    <!-- This is the URL of what we want the menu item to link to -->
                    <action>adminhtml/calendario</action>
                </calendario_calendario>
                <calendario_controladata translate="title" module="calendario">
                    <!-- This is how the menu text will be displayed -->
                    <title>Gerenciador de Datas</title>
                    <!-- This is the URL of what we want the menu item to link to -->
                    <action>adminhtml/controladata</action>
                </calendario_controladata>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <!-- Same as above, but instead of referencing the config/menu node, you reference the acl/resources node of adminhtml.xml -->
                    <sales>
                        <children>
                            <!-- Keep the same naming convention as above -->
                            <calendario_calendario module="calendario">
                                <!-- This is how the ACL text will be displayed on System > Permissions > Roles > Role > Role Resources -->
                                <title>Bloqueio de Datas</title>
                            </calendario_calendario>
                            <calendario_controladata module="calendario">
                                <!-- This is how the ACL text will be displayed on System > Permissions > Roles > Role > Role Resources -->
                                <title>Gerenciador de Datas</title>
                            </calendario_controladata>
                        </children>
                    </sales>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

> system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <calendario_controladata translate="label" module="calendario">
            <groups>
                <periodos_group translate="label" module="calendario">
                    <fields>
                        <madrugada_default translate="label">
                            <label>Madrugada - Periodo DEFAULT?</label>
                            <comment></comment>
                            <frontend_type>time</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </madrugada_default>
                    </fields>
                </periodos_group>
            </groups>
        </calendario_controladata>
    </sections>
</config>
```

> config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <IsabelaFlores_Calendario>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </IsabelaFlores_Calendario>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <calendario>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>IsabelaFlores_Calendario</module>
                    <frontName>calendario</frontName>
                </args>
            </calendario>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <calendario>
                <!-- This is where we define our helper directory -->
                <class>IsabelaFlores_Calendario_Helper</class>
            </calendario>
        </helpers>   
        <blocks>
            <calendario>
                <!-- Set a block definition and lookup directory -->
                <class>IsabelaFlores_Calendario_Block</class>
            </calendario>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <calendario>
                <class>IsabelaFlores_Calendario_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>calendario_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </calendario>
            <calendario_mysql4>
                <class>IsabelaFlores_Calendario_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <calendario>
                        <table>calendario</table>
                    </calendario>
                    <controladata>
                        <table>controladata</table>
                    </controladata>
                </entities>
            </calendario_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <calendario_setup>
                <setup>
                   <module>IsabelaFlores_Calendario</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                   <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </calendario_setup>
            <calendario_write>
                <connection>
                   <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </calendario_write>
            <calendario_read>
                <connection>
                   <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </calendario_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <!-- This is how we load our Adminhtml controllers -->
                    <modules>
                        <IsabelaFlores_Calendario before="Mage_Adminhtml">IsabelaFlores_Calendario_Adminhtml</IsabelaFlores_Calendario>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
            <calendario>
                <!--
                We again keep a nice naming convention and make our module upgrade proof by placing it in a separate folder
                - Since we are in the adminhtml node, this will look for the XML file in the app/design/adminhtml/default/default root folder
                -->
                <file>Calendario/calendario.xml</file>
            </calendario>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

> Module in Backend

[image]

Comment: Your file `system.xml` not similar in that picture.

Comment: It is because there is already a grid and a form inside a block, I would just like to add this label externally, would this be feasible or would it be better for me to use the existing block?

Answer (score 0):

**calendario_controladata** if this name your tab , try this code **system.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <sections>
            <calendario_controladata translate="label" module="calendario">
                <groups>
                    <periodos_group translate="label" module="calendario">
                        <fields>
                             <label>Madrugada - Periodo DEFAULT</label>
                             <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                             <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                             <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                             <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                             <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                <madrugada_default translate="label">
                                    <label>Madrugada - Periodo DEFAULT</label>
                                    <comment></comment>
                                    <frontend_type>time</frontend_type>
                                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            </madrugada_default>
                        </fields>
                    </periodos_group>
                </groups>
            </calendario_controladata>
        </sections>
    </config>
```

Comment: It did not work, I do not know if I'm erasing the tab name. I'm trying to put in a form created in a block, I access this page from Sales -> Manage Dates (Custom), here comes a grid and when I choose one of the option opens the page of the photo. The file is this here Block / Adminhtml / Controladata / Edit / Form.php